# ionic: scroll content with two fingers only

Tags: ionic-framework

I have `ion-scroll` content with elements which can be dragged around. The issue is actually not about disabling scrolling when dragging. The issue is that as the content elements fill practically the whole content area, whenever I want to scroll, actually a drag event happens.

Is it possible to define a scroll gesture with two fingers only? So whenever I'd be using two fingers, it would scroll, but when I use one finger, it drags.

```
 <ion-scroll id="queue-scroll" delegate-handle="queue-scroll" ng-drop="true">

    <div items="queue.items">
      <app-item 
        ng-drag-start="stopIonicScroll()" 
        on-release="startIonicScroll()" 
        ng-drag-data="item" 
        ng-drop-success="onDropComplete($data,$event,$index)" 
        ng-repeat="item in queue.items track by $index" />

    </div>
  </ion-scroll>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try out the dragging directive from ionic:
http://ionicframework.com/docs/api/directive/onDrag/

If that's not working, you need to get the `$event` from the dragging and prevent it yourself. You could check the `TouchList`: https://developer.mozilla.org/de/docs/Web/API/TouchList
And if you detect two touches (TouchList.length > 1), you stop dragging.